# How to setup debuging for rust in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, lldb, vscode-debugger, codelldb

So I am trying to get learn me some rust as part of this year's advent of code challange.

I have this setup: https://github.com/pschoffer/AdventOfCode/tree/master/2021

So each day is one subsubfolder. When I am inside some directory say: `cd 2021/02`. Running `cargo run` works just fine.

However, I would like to get the debugger to work too. When searching online I saw an extension [LLDB](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb) is used for that.

I tried a few variations on the config, but I always get this or a similar error.
[image]

My lunch config can be found [here](https://github.com/pschoffer/AdventOfCode/blob/master/.vscode/launch.json)

Would love to get any input on the setup as clearly I have no idea what I am doing:)

Comment: Do you compile it before running? Can use a build task for that.

Comment: And does the launched executable points to the correct one?

Comment: Thanks for the input @ChayimFriedman.

Would `cargo build` be the way to build?

I am not sure what is the executable here. It seems to generate this `target` folder. Nothing in there strikes me like an executable though:



`
    $ tree -L 2
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── input.txt
├── src
│   └── main.rs
├── target
│   ├── CACHEDIR.TAG
│   ├── debug
│   └── rls
└── test1.txt

4 directories, 6 files
`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting I seem to be non-able to figure out how to paste code block in the comment here.